# How to retrieve a conditionally set variable from inside a function?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

What can I do to retrieve a conditional variable from inside a function in the webpage being parsed by greasemonkey?

Something like this:

```
var myglobal = 5;

function myfunc() {
    myglobal = myglobal -1;
    if (myglobal == -1) {
        var this1 = 'Test';
        document.getElementById("mybutton").href = this1;
    }
}
```

In this case I would like to read what is in 'this1', either directly or modifying 'myglobal', calling 'myfunc' and somehow getting the value of href from 'mybutton'... any ideas?

Comment: Just get the `href` value: `document.getElementById("mybutton").href`. What's the problem?

Comment: myfunc is a counter, and I want to skip it, otherwise mybutton.href won't be set yet. Also, don't I need to use unsafeWindow to access it?

Comment: fyi: javascript variables are declared at the top of the scope (hoisted), `this1` is actually existent throughout the whole of `myfunc()` [see: "javascript hoisting"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually can't get a variable value from outside a scope like that, but you may not have to in this case.

> "myfunc is a counter, and I want to skip it, otherwise mybutton.href won't be set yet."

Based on the sample code, you might be able to cheat that timer just by using:

```
unsafeWindow.myglobal = 0;
```

(In fact, I use this exact technique on one very misguided training site.)

---

To answer the stated question further, you cannot get dynamic values from within such a scope but the initial state may be enough, as it appears to be for this question.

So you could get `myfunc()`s code and parse it with regex to obtain the desired value:

```
var theFunc     = unsafeWindow.myfunc.toString ();
var desiredHref = theFunc.match (/var\s+this1\s*=\s*["']([^"']+)["']/);
if (desiredHref.length > 1) {
    // Found!
    desiredHref = desiredHref[1];
}
```